# php pow function returns NAN

Tags: php, nan, pow

When I execute

```
echo pow( -0.3741569180353 , 0.2 ) ;
```

I am getting result `NAN`

While in excel and calculator, I am getting the answer -0.8215.

What is the solution to fix this as I am having lot of such calculations ?

Comment: Use `echo -0.3741569180353 ** 0.2 ;` with PHP >= 5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some consultation with the experts in Room #11, `pow()` won't work with the root of a negative number.
Should the answer be `0.8215` or `-0.8215`?

Quirkily, using the `**` (power) operator will work with the root of a negative number

```
echo -0.3741569180353 ** 0.2 ;
```

because `**` has higher precedence than `-`, so effectively what you're doing is

```
echo -(0.3741569180353 ** 0.2) ;
```

Comment: But when I am assigning to a variable, the same problem
`$v1 = -0.3741569180353;
$v2 = 0.2;
echo  $v1 ** $v2;`

Comment: `$v1 = -0.3741569180353;
$v2 = 0.2;
echo  $v1 ** $v2 ;
Result : NAN
echo  -( abs($v1) ** $v2 );`
Result : -0.82150603063756 `

Comment: `$v1 = -0.3741569180353; $v2 = 0.2; echo $v1 ** $v2 ;` `$v1` is a negative number.... hence a  complex result from the operation, so NaN. `echo -0.3741569180353 ** 0.2 ;` is calculating `0.3741569180353 ** 0.2` first (because `**` has precedence over `-`) and then applying the `-` unary operator

Comment: But if you have a lot of such calculations, I'd suggest that you work with a library capable of handling complex numbers

Answer (score 0):

Given `a` a negative number, its powers to integer exponents are defined as follows:

- `a`<sup>`0`</sup> is `0` - usually treated as positive;
- `a`<sup>`1`</sup> is `a` - negative;
- `a`<sup>`2`</sup> is `a*a` - positive;
- `a`<sup>`n`</sup> is negative for odd values of `n` and positive for even values of `n`.

The exponentiation of a negative base to a non-integer exponent is [not defined in real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases).
(It is, however, defined in complex numbers.)

The [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function is correct. It returns `NaN` because the result is not a real number.

The behaviour is even specified in the [Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php#refsect1-function.pow-examples) section of the documentation:

> ```
> echo pow(-1, 5.5); // PHP >=5.2.2: NAN
> ```